# Can not run virtual host website demo with wamp server 3.1.0

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I setup wamp server in my PC use windows 10.
Wamp start ok. I run link localhost ok.

I create a virtual host abcd.test success but it can not run.

I checked apache_error log:

```
[Sat Aug 04 21:52:05.462895 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13960:tid 628] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server. 
[Sat Aug 04 21:52:07.465001 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12684:tid 700] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited. 
[Sat Aug 04 21:52:07.489996 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13960:tid 628] AH00430: Parent: Child process 12684 exited successfully. 
[Sat Aug 04 21:52:08.278895 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16620:tid 752] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/5.6.31 configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Sat Aug 04 21:52:08.278895 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16620:tid 752] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Jul  7 2017 12:46:00 
[Sat Aug 04 21:52:08.278895 2018] [core:notice] [pid 16620:tid 752] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.27\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27' 
[Sat Aug 04 21:52:08.282891 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16620:tid 752] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 17360 
[Sat Aug 04 21:52:08.564039 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 17360:tid 728] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

I run cmd Command line:

```
'D:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.27\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27'*
```

[image]

File httpd:

```
#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
...
```

File virtual host:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wordpress.test
    DocumentRoot "d:/projects/wordpress"
    <Directory  "d:/projects/wordpress/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help me!

Comment: You should post the command prompt text as text (formatted as code), no image of text here!

Comment: You probably have `Listen *:80` two times in your configuration.  Apache can only bind once per port.  Or there is already another executable binding the same port.  Add your configuration in the question, otherwise we cannot help more than guesses.

Comment: This error happen when you moved from hdd to ssd and new wamp install.
Wamp run and display the greean color.
What do you want share configure?

Comment: The httpd.conf file, and any `Include` .conf files.  The `Listen` statements are in these files.

Comment: I just updated description file  `httpd.conf` and `httpd-vhost.conf`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `Listen` statements.  You can only have 1 `Listen` for 1 port.

The first one tells Apache to bind port 80, the second one tells it the same thing, hence the conflict.  See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

If you put

```
Listen 80
```

it will bind port 80 *on all interfaces*, so no need to specify it once for IPv4 and once for IPv6.  It will handle both automatically.